# Check if a string contains "viewBox" , if not I want to add it in the right position

Tags: java, svg, gradle

I want to check a `String` (SVG file) if it contains the `viewBox` attribute.
That is no problem for me but my question is, how I can add the attribute in the right place into the string?
I am using Gradle so I cannot use the batik library.

Comment: Why can you not use Batik while using Gradle?

Comment: Ok I found that I can use it, but I want to check a String and not a Svg-File..
So I dont need it anyway

Comment: gradle is groovy/kotlin with newer versions, try to find some string operations maybe, or explain what you need to do.

Comment: (Literally, you can't: Java `String`s are immutable.) (Describe what you want/need to achieve in excruciating detail.)

Answer (score 0):

Gradle scripts are based on Groovy which is based on Java, so you can use any existing Java library also from your buildscripts. Just add the Batik library to the build script dependencies like described at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:build_script_external_dependencies then you can use Batik in your build script.

Comment: He said he don't need it anyway, I presume the best approach is to create a custom task with some groovy goodness that will do all that String finding, inserting and saving for him.

Comment: @InjuredThePatient I started writing my answer before any comments were created and didn't see there were comments before I answered. I'll wait until he adds more information and then probably update the answer. Regarding the question, the answer is still correct. :-D